# moq internal interface in Silverlight 4. "Can not create proxy for types that are not accessible."

Tags: silverlight-4.0, moq, internalsvisibleto

I try to mock an internal interface in Silverlight 4, using moq-silverlight 4.0.10827.0.

I get an error "Can not create proxy for types that are not accessible." in a Castle.DynamicProxy.Generators.GeneratorException.

I have [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")] in the assemblyInfo of the tested assembly. I do not have any signed assemblies.

Answer (score 5):

Try including the public key as well:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100c547cac37abd99c8db225ef2f6c8a3602f3b3606cc9891605d02baa56104f4cfc0734aa39b93bf7852f7d9266654753cc297e7d2edfe0bac1cdcf9f717241550e0a7b191195b7667bb4f64bcb8e2121380fd1d9d46ad2d92d2d15605093924cceaf74c4861eff62abf69b9291ed0a340e113be11e6a7d3113e92484cf7045cc7")]
```

And make sure you also make the internals visible to the unit test assembly (assuming they're in a different assembly).

Answer (score 1):

The `InternalsVisibleTo` switch works only in this scenario: You have to apply it in the assembly containing the internals you want to be visible to another assembly. If it would work when you specify it in an assembly who wants to *consume* those internals, then it would be a great security leak!